# lost nigeria passport with valid us visa

Tags: air-travel

I entered USA in June for vacation and misplaced my passport. I need to go back to Nigeria ASAP though am permitted to stay in the USA for six months. Please what step do I need to take for me to replace the lost Visa in Nigeria. I planned to replace the lost passport before going back to my country.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make **really** sure that the passport is lost, and not just in another pocket.

2) Inform the local police that you lost the passport. This will make it more difficult for others to abuse your passport for [identity theft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theft_in_the_United_States).

3) Inform the Nigerian embassy or consulate that you lost the passport. Again that will make it more difficult for others to abuse your passport, and it is the first step towards getting a new passport or emergency travel document.